# I can't add either mdf file or sdf file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can connect any database in SQL Server Express but I can't add `.mdf` file using solution explorer

Whenever try it I get this exception

> A network related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

1. I have disabled firewall
2. All the protocols for SQL Server express are enabled
3. Allow remote connection checkbox is clicked
4. Uninstall skype and Teamviewer

I have no idea what is the reason

Comment: You don't "add an .mdf file", you connect to an instance of SQL Server (Express or other) and either connect to an existing database or attach a database file. What's your connection string?

Comment: I am sorry.I think I couldnt explain clearly there is no problem while connecting sqlserver instance .But when i right click Solution explrer and then add addNewItem and select Local database file computere freeze for a few seconds then  this error message appears .how can i specify connection string before creating database.Please correct me if  i am wrong

Comment: That's a completely different question, but still, you won't be able to create a local database if SQL Server *Express* isn't already installed *and* running on your development machine. Is the service running?

Comment: Yes  sqlexpress and sql browser are running .I always creating small applications with sqlexpress .The problem occurs just adding sdf or mdf files